# Update using join to sync two tables with conditions

Tags: sql-server, join, inner-join

database: SQL Server 2014

I have two tables with similar columns. I need to update TblTarget with values from TblSource. I have to compare several column values since the other table has no ID.

Select query gives me what I need:

```
SELECT 
    b.id
    a.mDate as mmDate, 
    b.mDate as wwDate, 
    b.Name, 
    b.Nr,
    b.address
FROM TblSource b 
    INNER JOIN TblTarget a
    ON  a.mDate = b.mDate AND
        a.Name = b.Name AND
        a.Nr = b.Nr AND
        a.address = b.address 
    WHERE   
        a.info = 'needs_more' AND
        a.data = 'kaput'
```

When I try to update :

```
UPDATE a
    SET a.id = b.id,
        a.mDate = b.mDate,
        a.Name = b.Name,    
        a.Nr = b.Nr,
        a.address = b.address,
        a.Surname = b.Surname,
        a.note = 'updated'
    FROM TblTarget a 
    JOIN TblSource b 
        ON  a.mDate = b.mDate AND
            a.Name = b.Name AND
            a.Nr = b.Nr AND
            a.address = b.address
        WHERE 
            a.info = 'needs_more' AND
            a.data = 'kaput' AND 
            a.note <> 'updated'
```

Result is:  (0) rows affected

Any ideas  ?

Comment: You should select the same as when updating to test the data. In the update query you have one extra condition `(AND a.note <> 'updated')` which might be filtering out your data.

Comment: Run the SELECT statement again including the <> 'updated' and see if you still get your results.

Comment: thanks, I think problem was NULL values which SQLServer handles it's own way. Now I get `Msg 8152, Level 16, State 13, Line 1
String or binary data would be truncated.` Have to check columns betwewn two tables I suppose.

Comment: Check column datatypes